# Python Spark: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'orderBy'

Tags: python, pyspark

From a dataframe that contains anime information, I wanted to see the average score of each Genre but came up with this error that I don't understand.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myKcD.png)

I'm expecting a dataframe with the average score (using .avg) of each genre:
Romance - 9.1 Horror - 7.8 Fantasy - 7.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to aggregate the grouped data in some way before calling `.orderBy()`.
`.groupBy()` returns a [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) object.

This should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

origin_table \
    .groupBy('Genres') \
    .avg(col('Score').alias('Score')) \
    .orderBy('Score')
```

Comment: TypeError: Column is not iterable